# Set Camera with CTRL + ALT + num 0 = Gray screen, no object

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'm still in my first weeks of working on Blender and just starting my first tutorial project at the moment.

I ran into a problem that I have been having a hard time troubleshooting.  Everything in my project seems fine, but when I go to set my camera with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 0</kbd> I just get a gray box.  I can navigate around to break this view, but even when I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to view a quick camera render it's nothing but a gray box.

I have checked my clipping points and those see normal. Any thoughts?

Viewport settings:
[image: viewport settings]

Camera settings:
[image: camera settings]

What I get with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 0</kbd>:
[image: what I get with CTRL + ALT + num 0]

When moving slightly outside of camera view:
[image: when moving slightly outside of camera view]

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing more about your project, but based on the spacing of the gridlines, it looks like your Donut is really small... like, tiny. Is it possible the camera is too close (despite the .1m near clip distance)? Try scaling the object up and see what happens (don't forget to apply scale (Ctrl+A) afterwards if you scale in object mode).

Comment: i am pretty sure Christopher is right, but i you still have problems, pls provide blend file so we don't have to guess, thx

Comment: The camera's default 0.1m of minimum distance is actually not that great. It's 10cm, there can be a lot of things within 10cm. And when you do a close up, it's a huge distance not being rendered. 0.1m (1cm) as it's the default in the viewport is way better and more versatile whilst keeping things stable still.

Comment: Thank you, scaling up resolves the issue.  Must have had clipping after all.  Thank you for this solve!  Appreciate it!